# Como posso diminuir o tamanho desta função?

Tags: javascript, html

É uma função simples, porém está começando a virar um monstro, a única coisa que muda é o número no final de cada palavra. Alguém tem alguma dica de como encurtar esse código? Sem minificar
Obs: não quero diminuir o tamanho em KB, mas em linhas.

```
function adc_atalho(qm){
    if (qm == 1 ) {
        document.getElementById("botaoAtalho1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("botao1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("btRemover1").style.display = "inline";
    }

    else if (qm == 2) {
        document.getElementById("botaoAtalho2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("botao2").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("btRemover2").style.display = "inline";
    }

    else if (qm == 3) {
        document.getElementById("botaoAtalho3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("botao3").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("btRemover3").style.display = "inline";
    }

    else if (qm == 4) {
        document.getElementById("botaoAtalho4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("botao4").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("btRemover4").style.display = "inline"; 
    }

    else if (qm == 5) {
        document.getElementById("botaoAtalho5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("botao5").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("btRemover5").style.display = "inline"; 
    }

    else if (qm == 6) {
        document.getElementById("botaoAtalho6").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("botao6").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("btRemover6").style.display = "inline"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Depende do contexto da pagina, olhando assim fica meio difícil entender o que faz,
mas eu aconselharia a encaixar um vetor ai, ficaria bem mais simples

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma vez que há um padrão no código onde todos os `if` dependem somente de `qm`, podias fazer assim:

```js
function adc_atalho(qm) {
    document.getElementById("botaoAtalho" + qm).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("botao" + qm).style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("btRemover" + qm).style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: Sergio, não seria adequado validar se o elemento existe de fato antes de alterar seu estilo? Evitando possíveis erros.

Comment: @MathiasFalci é uma possibilidade, há mais optimizações como cache dos elementos, mas mantive-me só no escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Muito obrigado Sérgio, eu estava tentado fazer com vetor, mas, felizmente não é preciso utilizá-lo.

Answer (score 5):

Caso queira validar antes...

```js
function adc_atalho(qm){ 
    var btnAtalho = document.getElementById("botaoAtalho" +qm );
    var btn = document.getElementById("botao" + qm);
    var btnRemover = document.getElementById("btRemover" + qm);
    
    if(btnAtalho) btnAtalho.style.display = "none";
    if(btn) btn.style.display = "inline";
    if(btnRemover) btnRemover.style.display = "inline";
}

adc_atalho(1);
```

```html
<button id="botaoAtalho1">
atalho
</button>
<button id="botao1">
btn
</button>
<button id="btRemover1">
remover
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode validar com menos linhas ainda, restringindo o a variável `qm` dentro de um conjunto de valores:

```
<script>
function adc_atalho(qm) {
    if(qm > 0 && qm <= 6){ // aqui eu restringo de 0 a 6 o valor de qm
        document.getElementById("botaoAtalho" + qm).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("botao" + qm).style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("btRemover" + qm).style.display = "inline";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ai você está verificando se o parâmetro foi passado corretamente, não se o elemento existe no DOM

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Não, estou verificando valores válidos. Me parece que os elementos não são dinâmicos, logo, ao meu ver, não há muita necessidade de verificar se existe no DOM.